# TypeScript: is there a way to parameterize an enum

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-i18next

I have this `enum` defined in our codebase.

```
enum EventDesc {
  EVENT1 = 'event 1',
  EVENT2 = 'event 2',
  EVENT3 = 'event 3'
}
```

`EVENT1`, `EVENT2`, `EVENT3` are the event types defined on the backend. And `event 1`, `event 2`, `event 3` are the event descriptions that get rendered on the UI, for some reason they are not defined on the backend. I used an `enum` to make the mapping here and to get the corresponding event description.

However now we are supporting internationalization using `react-i18next`, meaning that the descriptions have to be translated for a number of languages. In other words they cannot be hardcoded like this only using English.

Our current approach for injecting translation texts is that we have a json file defined for every language we care about and we use them with `react-i18next` like this

```
import {useTranslation} from 'react-i18next';

export const Page = () => {
  const {i: i18n } = useTranslation()
  
  return (
    <div>{i18n("siteTitle")}</div>
  )

}
```

So before I am getting the event description by just look up the key in the `enum`, e.g. `EventDesc[eventType]`. Now obviously it won't work with `react-i18next`. I wonder is there a way to parameterize the enum's value using Generics so we can do something like this `EventDesc<'en'>[eventType]` or `EventDesc<'jp'>[eventType]`. But then I realized even with this it might not work because with `enum` we are always defining the event description at compiler time and `react-i18next` would only pick up the translation text from the `json` files during runtime.

Is there a better alternative than using an `enum` to store the event description data?

Comment: You don't need an enum; my guess is that you can write an interface for your json files and use a type for its keys.  But I have no react-i18next experience and I don't see a [mcve] in the question (the enum is something you're not going to use, example json files are not present, and your example [errors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=3#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwK4GcCmAVKBDAdigG2xmAlwF84AzKCEOAcijWwGMYBaYARgA5c0ADxgMA3AFgAUEMiw4rMingAFbAHM0cALxwAFAEptAPkRS48xfATAAXHB784lHakw58REmQPmzcZjBIULh6fuYAPAAmwABuRtZ8uLoARCjAMJjpBGjJ+uThAPTRcX76UuRAA)) so I'm not sure how to advise further.

Answer (score 0):

Using this approach, you can force translations to be maintained - missing translations in the matrix show as compiler errors against an instance of GlobalDictionary.

The global dictionary could be maintained in a single const, but I've shown how you could separate translations - e.g. to keep them in separate files.

In VSCode save this file as .ts and try adding an event or a language and following through the compiler errors until the translations are complete again.

```js
namespace Internationalization {
  type Event = 'event 1' | 'event 2' | 'event 3';

  type Language = 'en' | 'jp' | 'fr'

  type Translation<L extends Language> = {
    [K in Event]: string
  }

  type GlobalDictionary = {
    [L in Language]: Translation<L>
  }

  const frenchDictionary: Translation<'fr'> = {
    "event 1": 'hoh',
    "event 2": 'hi',
    "event 3": 'hoh',
  }

  const babel: GlobalDictionary = {
    en: {
      "event 1": 'yo',
      "event 2": 'hi',
      "event 3": 'ug',
    },
    jp: {
      "event 1": 'um',
      "event 2": 'er',
      "event 3": 'ah',
    },
    fr: frenchDictionary
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, trying to parameterize an enum is not the way to work in Angular or React.
Most of the time we want to show the enums as a select DOM element in html, but the words are expected to be translated.
This is one approach to display a gender enum as a select element only in english, no translation at all.
[What user sees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GV0r.png)

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';


function getLengthEnum(ENUMERATION:any):number{
  let l_items : any[] = Object.values(ENUMERATION).filter((item) => !isNaN(Number(item)));
  return l_items.length;
}
enum Gender{
  'None',
  'Male',
  'Female'
}
export interface MyAplicacionState {  
  i_genderSelected : number
}
class MyAplicacion extends React.Component<{},MyAplicacionState> {
  private li_indexesGenders : number[];
  constructor() {
    super({});      
    let i_numGenders : number = getLengthEnum(Gender);    
    this.li_indexesGenders = Array.from(Array(i_numGenders).keys());//[...Array(i_numGenders).keys()];    
    this.handleChangeGender = this.handleChangeGender.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      i_genderSelected : 0
    };
  }

  handleChangeGender(event:any) : void {
    this.setState({i_genderSelected: event.target.value});
  }

  render(){    
    const listOptionsGender = this.li_indexesGenders.map((i_index:number) =>
          <option value={i_index}>{Gender[i_index]}</option>
      );
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <header className='App-header'>
          <img src={logo} className='App-logo' alt='logo' />
          <select value={this.state.i_genderSelected} onChange={this.handleChangeGender}>
            {listOptionsGender}
          </select>        
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }  
}

export default MyAplicacion;
```

This is one approach to display a gender enum as a select element using react-i18next.
[What user sees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQRqQ.png)

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

const resTrans = {
  de: {
    translation: {
      'None': 'Keine',
      'Male': 'Männlich',
      'Female': 'Weiblich'
    }
  },
  fr: {
    translation: {
      'None': 'Aucun',
      'Male': 'Homme',
      'Female': 'Femme'
    }
  }
};

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
    resources: resTrans,
    lng: 'de',
    fallbackLng: 'de',
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false
    }
});

function getLengthEnum(ENUMERATION:any):number{
  let l_items : any[] = Object.values(ENUMERATION).filter((item) => !isNaN(Number(item)));
  return l_items.length;
}
enum Gender{
  'None',
  'Male',
  'Female'
}
export interface MyAplicacionState {  
  i_genderSelected : number,
  i_langSelected : number,
  ls_gendersTranslated : string[]
}
class MyAplicacion extends React.Component<{},MyAplicacionState> {
  private li_indexesGenders : number[];
  constructor() {
    super({});      
    let i_numGenders : number = getLengthEnum(Gender);    
    this.li_indexesGenders = Array.from(Array(i_numGenders).keys());//[...Array(i_numGenders).keys()];    
    this.handleChangeGender = this.handleChangeGender.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeLang = this.handleChangeLang.bind(this);
    this.getListGendersTranslated = this.getListGendersTranslated.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      i_genderSelected : 0,
      i_langSelected : 0,
      ls_gendersTranslated : this.getListGendersTranslated()
    };
  }

  handleChangeGender(event:any) : void {
    this.setState({i_genderSelected: event.target.value});
  }

  handleChangeLang(event:any) : void {
    let i_indexLang : number = parseInt(event.target.value);    
    let s_lang : string = 'de';
    if(i_indexLang===1)s_lang = 'fr';
    i18n.changeLanguage(s_lang);    
    this.setState({i_langSelected: i_indexLang, ls_gendersTranslated : this.getListGendersTranslated()});
  }
  //from enum list to string list
  getListGendersTranslated() : string[]{
    let ls_gendersTranslated1 : string[] = [];
    this.li_indexesGenders.forEach((i_index : number)=>{
      ls_gendersTranslated1.push(i18n.t(Gender[i_index]));
    }); 
    return ls_gendersTranslated1;
  }

  render(){    
    const listOptionsGender = this.li_indexesGenders.map((i_index:number) =>
          <option value={i_index}>{this.state.ls_gendersTranslated[i_index]}</option>
      );
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <header className='App-header'>
          <img src={logo} className='App-logo' alt='logo' />
          <select value={this.state.i_genderSelected} onChange={this.handleChangeGender}>
            {listOptionsGender}
          </select>
          <select value={this.state.i_langSelected} onChange={this.handleChangeLang}>
            <option value={0}>Deutsche</option>
            <option value={1}>Française</option>
          </select>          
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }  
}

export default MyAplicacion;
```

`ls_gendersTranslated` is the list of genders(strings) in the language selected.
`ls_gendersTranslated` is inside the state so it changes whenever the language selected changes.
using `li_indexesGenders` and `getListGendersTranslated` you can show enum as a select.
`resTrans`,  `getLengthEnum` and `Gender` enum should be in other ts and json files.
Excuse me about this weird notation.